# Django rest framework user model permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building a web app using REST API and I have a 4 users that I want them to access only the content they have added to the backend. I have created 3 users say farmers(3 farmers) and added content using each one of them. However, I have been unable to implement permissions such that a farmer can view and delete only what they added.

Here's is my code in `models.py`

```
    User = get_user_model()

    # Create your models here.

    class Tender(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_due = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    contact = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Input(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    contact = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Investor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    contact = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Here's what I implemented in `permissions.py`

```
    from rest_framework import permissions


    class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True
            if request.user == obj.author:
                return True
            return False

    class IsOwnerOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        
            if request.user == obj.user :
                return True
            return False
```

Here is my code in `views.py`:

```
    from requests import request
    from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
    from rest_framework import viewsets, status, permissions
    from django.http import Http404, JsonResponse
    from rest_framework.views import Response
    from .models import Tender, Input , Investor
    from .serializers import TenderViewSerializer, InputViewSerializer, InvestViewSerializer
    from user.models import User
    from user.permissions import IsOwnerOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly


    # Create your views here.

    class TenderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = TenderViewSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

        def get_queryset(self):
            if self.request.user.is_tender_holder:
                queryset = Tender.objects.all()
                return  queryset
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)
        
        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_tender_holder:
                new_tender = Tender.objects.create(
                    name=request.data["name"],
                    description=request.data["description"],
                    date_due=request.data["date_due"],
                    location=request.data["location"],
                    contact=request.data['contact']
                    )
                
                new_tender.save()
                
                serializer = TenderViewSerializer(new_tender)

                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)

        def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_tender_holder:
                try:
                    instance =self.get_object()
                    self.perform_destroy(instance)
                except Http404:
                    pass

                return Response({"message": "Tender deleted successfully"})
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)

            # def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      




    class InvestorViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = InvestViewSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        #queryset = Investor.objects.all()

        def get_queryset(self):
           if self.request.user.is_investor:
                queryset = Investor.objects.all()
                return  queryset
           else: 
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)

        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_investor:
                new_investment = Investor.objects.create(
                    name=request.data["name"],
                    description=request.data["description"],
                    location=request.data["location"],
                    contact=request.data['contact']
                   )
            
                new_investment.save()
            
                serializer = InvestViewSerializer(new_investment)

                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)

        def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_investor:
                try:
                    instance =self.get_object()
                    self.perform_destroy(instance)
                except Http404:
                    pass

                return Response({"message": "Investment deleted successfully"})
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)



    class InputViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = InputViewSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
        #queryset = Input.objects.all()

        def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_input_holder or self.request.user.is_superuser:
                user = self.request.user
                return  Input.objects.filter(id=user.id)
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)



        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_input_holder or self.request.user.is_superuser:
                new_input = Input.objects.create(
                    name=request.data["name"],
                    description=request.data["description"],
                    price=request.data["price"],
                    quantity=request.data["quantity"],
                    contact=request.data['contact']
                  )
            
                new_input.save()
            
                serializer = InputViewSerializer(new_input)

                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)


        def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_input_holder or self.request.user.is_superuser:
                try:
                    instance =self.get_object()
                    self.perform_destroy(instance)
                except Http404:
                    pass

                return Response({"message": "Input deleted successfully"})
            else:
                return Response({"NO_ACCESS": "Access Denied"}, status=401)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
    # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True

    # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

This code give view permission to all users

If you want to restrict all permission you should try something like this

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

Comment: That restricts permissions for all users but what if I want to enable permissions for certain users?

Comment: Yes this will give permission to the author only